# SQL how can I get list of users and departments with filter by position?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Please help me, how can i get a list of users of the department with a filter by position?

```
CREATE TABLE COMPANY 
(
    ID INT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    NAME VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (ID),
    UNIQUE KEY COMPANY_NAME (NAME)
);

CREATE TABLE USER
(
    ID INT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    NAME VARCHAR(255),
    LASTNAME VARCHAR(255),
    DATE_OF_BIRTH DATE ,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID),
);

CREATE TABLE POSITION
(
    ID INT NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    POSITION VARCHAR (50),
    USERID INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (USERID) REFERENCES USER(ID)
);

CREATE TABLE DEPARTMENT
(
    ID INT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    USER_ID INT NOT NULL,
    COMPANY_ID INT NOT NULL,
    DEPARTMENT_CATEGORY VARCHAR(50),
    PRIMARY KEY (ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (USER_ID) REFERENCES USER(ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (COMPANY_ID) REFERENCES COMPANY(ID)
);

CREATE TABLE CATEGORY 
(
    ID INT NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    NAME VARCHAR (50),
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

CREATE TABLE DEPARTMENT_CATEGORY
(
     DEPARTMENT_ID INT NOT NULL,
     CATEGORY_ID INT NOT NULL,
     FOREIGN KEY (DEPARTMENT_ID) REFERENCES DEPARTMENT(ID),
     FOREIGN KEY (CATEGORY_ID) REFERENCES CATEGORY(ID)
);
```

Please help me!!

Comment: add  a proper data sample  .. the expected  result and the query you are using  ..

Comment: You need to elaborate much more, this is too vague.  Give example data, example use cases and the desired results.  Also, why is this both `postgresql` and `mysqli`?

Comment: Join your relevant tables in your `FROM` clause and aggregate with a `GROUP BY`. Something like `SELECT count(user.id), department.id FROM user INNER JOIN department ON user.id = department.user_id INNER JOIN position on user.id = position.userid WHERE position.position = "SOME POSITION" GROUP BY department.id` Why tag `mysqli`? Please share sample data and expected results for better answers. If you are stuck making this work, perhaps ask your teacher for some extra help.

Comment: Please read [ask].  You need to show some level of effort at an attempt, or don't expect much help here.

Answer (score 1):

it look like you wanted to display results from department and position table that has both the data you need, but be specific about your filter (position) as u need to provide it in your where clause

```
select user_ID, department
from department as a
join user as b
on a. user_id = b. user_id
where position = 'put the specific position you wanted to be filtered here'
```

but your two userID columns are written differently as (User_id or USERID) correct that too not get failure result when you execute the task